# (basic) profiling of a Windows Forms application in a live environment

Tags: c#, .net, profiling

I have a c# Windows Forms application which is slowing down or even freezing after a day or so when deployed on a particular customer's site. I would love to rewrite this inherited project from scratch but for now the potential sources of the problem are rather widespread.

Can anyone suggest a way to perform some basic profiling (even "poor man's profiling"/break-and-sample) on a dotNET application in a live environment without completely crippling the performance.

Given the severity of the slow-down in the application, I guess that just a few data-points should be enough to find the cause.

Comment: You may use Windows performance counters. At least you may start with memory usage, threads, exceptions and locks.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the app does, but if this only on one customers site, that suggests an environmental discrepancy, or their usage pattern (e.g. they never restart the app...) is different. Think you need to get a handle on what that might be first. basic performance counters might give you a clue, there again may be not...

Comment: Visual studio(Professional or above) has inbuilt profiler you can find under Analyse tab.

Comment: I think it needs to be a debug build. When it's getting really slow, you shouldn't need more than a couple stackshots to see if the problem is in the app code. (I'm thinking of other possible issues like GC, memory thrashing, etc. Even so, amid the general agony a couple stackshots won't hurt much more.) How you get them on a customer's machine I'm not sure.